# Simple injector webapi authorization attribute

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I'm trying to create a custom authorization-attribute for my WebApi project.

In this attribute I would like to inject an IAuthModule object. I have no clue how I could implement this. I've found some solutions on the web but I have not been successful with any of them.

This is what I have so far:

```c#
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // WebApi config
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // SimpleInjector
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

    container.Register<IAuthModule, CoreAuthModule>();

    container.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);

    container.Verify();

    config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Setup Oauth
    ConfigureOAuth(app, container.GetInstance<IAuthModule>());

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

and the attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // how can I inject something here?
    public IAuthModule AuthModule { get; set; }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Simple Injector Web API integration guide](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html) goes into more details about this in the [Injecting dependencies into Web API filter attributes](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#injecting-dependencies-into-web-api-filter-attributes) section. What it basically describes is that you need to do two things:

1. Use the `RegisterWebApiFilterProvider` extension method to allow Simple Injector to build-up Web API attributes.
2. Register a custom `IPropertySelectionBehavior` to make sure Simple Injector will inject dependencies into your attribute's properties.

So this basically comes down to adding the following registration:

```cs
var container = new Container();

container.Options.PropertySelectionBehavior = new ImportPropertySelectionBehavior();

container.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Where the `ImportPropertySelectionBehavior` is implemented as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using SimpleInjector.Advanced;

class ImportPropertySelectionBehavior : IPropertySelectionBehavior {
    public bool SelectProperty(Type type, PropertyInfo prop) {
        return prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ImportAttribute)).Any();
    }
}
```

This custom `IPropertySelectionBehavior` enables explicit property injection where properties are marked with the `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportAttribute` attribute. Any property that is marked with this attribute will get injected.

Do note that dependency injection in attributes is sub optimal as described [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: The new version of Simple Injector does not `RegisterWebApiFilterProvider` method.

Comment: @Steven is there an alternative to `RegisterWebApiFilterProvider` in SimpleInjector 4? *Edit* @Chandermani found this: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#injecting-dependencies-into-web-api-filter-attributes 
Basically just use the service locator (anti) pattern.